# Не видит папку common в import и экземпляр класса GoogleApiClient

Tags: java, android, google-play-services

Добавил *depencies*:

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:8.4.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.4.0'
```

Добавил в манифест файл:

```
<meta-data
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
    android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
```

Все равно не видит ни папки common в импорте, ни экземляр класса GoogleApiClient. Что делать?

Comment: а если убрать первую строку `compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:8.4.0'` ?

Comment: Если вы прописали compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.4.0', то  compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:8.4.0' подрублены автоматически. Кстати, после того как прописали в градле справа вверху кнопку "sync" нажали?